# Negative Indexing & Slicing Python

Tags: python, list, indexing, reverse

Long time reader first time poster, ever.

I am trying to understand all I can about indexing, slicing, negative indexing, etc. with lists.

If I have a list:

```
toeFriendly_terms=['feet', 'shoes', 'socks', 'sandals', 'boots', 'toe rings']
```

**Ask 1: I would like to print() this list in reverse.**

**Q: Is it possible to use negative indexing to do this?** 
**Q: If so, how?**
**Q: If not, what is the proper way to do this?** 
**Q: If you can do it but there is a better way how do you do it?**

Ask 2: I looked around on here and found the .reverse() function but this opened up more questions.

```
names=['fanny', 'david', 'jimmy', 'hwang', 'esther']
#first three - fanny, david and jimmy
print('1. ', names[0:3])#stops right before 3 to give just what you need
#last three 
print('2. ', names[2:])#did not designate an end because I wanted all of it to come through
print('3. ', names[:-1]) #calls right up to before -1 
names2=names.reverse() #still affects the original list
print('4. ',names )
```

Q: Is there any way to preserve the original list so the reverse function doesn't affect whatever other work I've been doing with the list? (I am very new so I still do not fully understand if just duplicating the list is way easier or even more efficient..)

Q: What kind of real-world, 'on the job' applications does .reverse() have?

Thanks! That is all for now.

Comment: Welcome ! usually it's better to ask different questions independently, event if they are related.

Comment: Regarding your last Q, `.reverse()` can be used in the real-world (for example) when you want to save some memory: imagine your list is huge and you don't really need to keep the original version, so instead of copying it in reverse order (`list(reversed(names))` or `names[::-1]`) you can use `.reverse()` to mutate it in place.

Comment: Thanks @JoseKilo! I didn't want to spam with a bunch of questions on the first go ;) 

Your answer was super insightful. I didn't know about reversed only .reverse and I don't know what :: does yet. I will search on these and learn more. Appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0):

You are right in that calling `some_list.reverse()` mutates the original list, which you might expect or not (if not, keep reading).

You can use slicing to reverse the list like this: `some_list[::-1]`.

Note that there is always the `reversed()` method, which returns an iterator. If you want to get the reversed list all at once, you can just (surprise) turn it into a list: `list(reversed(some_list))`.

Comment: Thanks Don. So there are three ways to do this it seems:

**1.**  .reverse() - mutates the original list

**2.** some_list[::-1] - 'Further, to print whole List in reverse order, use [::-1].' [link]https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list/

**3.** reversed() - I can't anything really explaining this. Maybe the documentation. I'll go check that.

**Thanks again Don.**